# Работа с архивами.Java.Выгрузка файлов

Tags: java, android, файлы, загрузка, zip

Пишу под андроид подобие некой книжки, "листы книги" храню в виде html-страничек, странички в архиве.
Требуется из архива взять страницы и загрузить в WebView (элемент отображения html-страниц).

Возможно ли по ссылке (или названию файла в архиве) вытягивать файл из архива?

Пытался с `java.util.zip.ZipFile` и `java.util.zip.ZipEntry`, но находил инфу только под сохранение файлов в архив, взятие инфы о архиве и т.п.. Так же `ZipInputStream`. Информации много, но не то. Не работал раньше с архивами.

Comment: `WebView`? Почему не указали тэг `android` к вопросу? Не проще ли хранить html в assets?

Comment: Вопрос не очень связан с андроидом, поставили задачу загрузки книги через архив, там дальше будет делать редактор книги, и там будет лучше в архив все собирать

Answer (score 1):

Через ZipInputStream считываете содержимое страницы в строку. А потом засовываете строку в WebView.

Статья по работе с архивами 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/264701/

Статья по работе с webview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata

P.S. Еще можно с гитхаба скачать исходники fbread который очень замечательно работает с архивами (fb2 - по сути своей zip архив)

P.S.S. Както так. Почитайте статью по ссылке на хабре, которую я Вам дал.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) > -1) {
               куданибудь используем порцию считанных данных

            }
            zis.closeEntry();
        }
        zis.close();
        is.close();
```

Comment: На хабе видел статью, там упаковывают БД в архив, а ZipInputStream считывать может отдельный файл?